# Will this route work in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am making a twitter like web app in rails, following a course. I am trying to change the path but every time i start the server i get an eror and the server shuts down.

this is the path:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resources :posts
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
end
```

I have done routes before but they haven't looked like that. I think this is a ruby route where as i'm on rails. I'm not too sure. I thought they would work.

Comment: What version of rails are you running? Those are old rails 2? I believe routes. Ruby doesn't have routes per say. That's a rails feature.

Comment: The latest, 3.2 i think. Ah that makes sense now! Thank you

Comment: these routes are of Rails 2.x versions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resource would look something like this

```
PlatformAuth::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
end
```

for the map.connect it's more like a named route it would look something like

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

That will make all your controller actions available through a get request. Not sure if that's really want you want though.

Comment: What do the ()'s add? Do they require that in order to have an :id paramater, you have to have passed a :action parameter?

Comment: That just specifies that what is inside of it is optional. Action, id, and format are optional. That nesting will only allow id to come up if there's an action and same logic for format.